# Reshape and indexing in MATLAB and Python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, reshape, tensor

I have a code in Matlab which I need to translate in Python. A point here that shapes and indexes are really important since it works with tensors. I'm a little bit confused since it seems that it's enough to use `order='F'` in python `reshape()`. But when I work with 3D data I noticed that it does not work. For example, if `A` is an array from 1 to 27 in python

```
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 7,  8,  9]],

       [[10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18]],

       [[19, 20, 21],
        [22, 23, 24],
        [25, 26, 27]]])
```

if I perform `A.reshape(3, 9, order='F')` I get

```
[[ 1  4  7  2  5  8  3  6  9]
 [10 13 16 11 14 17 12 15 18]
 [19 22 25 20 23 26 21 24 27]]
```

In Matlab for `A = 1:27` reshaped to [3, 3, 3] and then to [3, 9] it seems that I get another array:

```
1     4     7    10    13    16    19    22    25
2     5     8    11    14    17    20    23    26
3     6     9    12    15    18    21    24    27
```

And SVD in Matlab and Python gives different results. So, is there a way to fix this?

And maybe you know the correct way of operating with multidimensional arrays in Matlab -> python, like should I get the same SVD for arrays like arange(1, 13).reshape(3, 4) and in Matlab 1:12 -> reshape(_, [3, 4]) or what is the correct way to work with that? Maybe I can swap axes somehow in python to get the same results as in Matlab? Or change the order of axes in `reshape(x1, x2, x3,...)` in Python?

Comment: In Matlab `reshape(A,3,3,3)` give the same result as your initial Python array.

Comment: In Matlab `A = 1:27` is equivalent `A = np.array(range(1,28))` in Python.
And in Matlab `reshape(A,3,3,3)` is quivalent `A.reshape(3,3,3)` in Python.

Comment: Yes, I know. But what if I want to reshape (3, 3, 3) array to (3, 9)? Seems that the order of elements is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issues, until I found this wikipedia article: [row- and column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order)

Python (and C) organizes the data arrays in row major order. As you can see in your first example code, the elements first increases with the columns:

```
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
          - - - -> increasing
```

Then in the rows

```
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
      [ 4,   <--- new element
```

When all columns and rows are full, it moves to the next page.

```
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
    [ 4,  5,  6],
    [ 7,  8,  9]],

   [[10,  <-- new element in next page
```

In matlab (as fortran) increases first the rows, then the columns, and so on.

For N-dimensionals arrays it looks like:

- Python (row major -> last dimension is contiguous): [dim1,dim2,...,dimN]
- Matlab (column major -> first dimension is contiguous): the same tensor in memory would look the other way around .. [dimN,...,dim2,dim1]

If you want to export n-dim. arrays from python to matlab, the easiest way is to permute the dimensions first:
(in python)

```python
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as sio
A=np.reshape(range(1,28),[3,3,3])
sio.savemat('A',{'A':A})
```

(in matlab)

```matlab
load('A.mat')
A=permute(A,[3 2 1]);%dimensions in reverse ordering
reshape(A,9,3)' %gives the same result as A.reshape([3,9]) in python
```

Just notice that the (9,3) an the (3,9) are intentionally putted in reverse order.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation! So, what is the correct way to 'translate' code from Matlab to python in terms in Matlab we have `reshape(A, [x1, x2, x3, ..])` then in python it should be `A.reshape(..., x3, x2, x1)` right?

Comment: If the tensor A was created in python, yes.

If you are importing a tensor created firstly in matlab to python (or viceversa) you first need to permute its dimensions (`permute()` in matlab, `np.moveaxis()` in python), and then do the reshaping as you mention.

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab

```
A = 1:27;
A = reshape(A,3,3,3);
B = reshape(A,9,3)'
B =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18
    19    20    21    22    23    24    25    26    27
size(B)

ans =

     3     9
```

In Python

```
A = np.array(range(1,28))
A = A.reshape(3,3,3)
B = A.reshape(3,9)
B
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
       [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]])
np.shape(B)
 (3, 9)
```